# passing base64 string in url

Tags: php, base64, encode

i tried passing the following base64 string in the url and its showing me "Request URI too lon error"

```
$data = "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";
```

how can i pass long base64 into url for encoding?

Comment: You could perhaps use a url shortening service such as bit.ly? Or send the data in a POST request

Comment: @RamRaider this won't work as the Url is to long and the url shorterer would redirect to the invalid url

Comment: You have to use POST or Session variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Apache, the limit is a configurable value, [LimitRequestLine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline). Change this value to something larger than its default of 8190 if you want to support a longer request URI.

However, note that if you're actually running into this limit, you are probably abusing GET to begin with. You should use POST to transmit this sort of data -- especially since you even concede that you're using it to update values. If you check the link above, you'll notice that Apache even says "Under normal conditions, the value should not be changed from the default."